# Java Steganography coding or encoding bug

Tags: java, steganography

I'm writing an application to hide animage in another image using LSB. The encoding returns an image that differs from the image that was hidden and after searching the problem for quite some time now, i think i became seriously blind, when it comes to my code.

If somebody could take a look and give me a hint, I would be very thankful. The significant code below and the whole project (if somebody would want to test it) under the link: https://github.com/miassma/Steganography.git

```
public class SteganographyOperationsUtil {   

/*checking if the image to hide can fit the hiding image
 it returns the range of shades of gray that can be kept in the hiding image*/

public static int checkImages(ImageModel hiding, ImageModel toHide, ImageModel copyOfToHide){
        int hidingSize = hiding.getWidth() * hiding.getHeight();
        int toHideSize = toHide.getWidth() * toHide.getHeight();
        int header = 40;            

        int value = 8;
        while((toHideSize * value + header) > hidingSize){  //if doesnt fit, reducing one range, checking again
            value--;
            if(value==0){
                break;                    
            }
        }
        if(value == 0) return -1;
        if(value<8) posterize(copyOfToHide, (int)pow(2, value)); //run the posterisation if needed
        return (int)pow(2, value);
}

/*  preparing the hiding image
    we need zero on each LSB
    */
public static void prepareHidingImage(ImageModel imgModel){
    for (int x = 0; x < imgModel.getWidth(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < imgModel.getHeight(); ++y) {
            int color = imgModel.getImage().getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[1])[0];
            int temp = 254;
            int newColor = color & temp;
            int[] newColorPixel = {newColor};
            imgModel.getImage().getRaster().setPixel(x, y, newColorPixel);
        }
    }        
    imgModel.imageChanged();
}


//fullfill by leading zeros with the lenght of the option
public static String fillString(String toFill, int option){
    String zero = "0";
    if (toFill.length() < option){            
        int temp = option - toFill.length();
        do{                
            toFill = zero.concat(toFill);
        }while(--temp >0);
    }        
    return toFill;
}

/* fullfill the string to get the color matching the posterisation range
       for example  1 will be 11111111 (2 ranges of gray)
        101 will become 10110110 (3 ranges of gray)
        1011 will become 10111011 (4 ranges of gray)
*/
public static String complete(String toComplete){
    while (toComplete.length() < 9){
        toComplete = toComplete+toComplete;
    }
    toComplete = toComplete.substring(0, 8); 
    return toComplete;
}

//hiding Image
public static void hidingOperation(ImageModel hiding, ImageModel toHide, int value){

   prepareHidingImage(hiding);

   String posterisation = Integer.toString(value-1, 2);
   String hiddenWidth = Integer.toString(toHide.getWidth(), 2);
   String hiddenHeight = Integer.toString(toHide.getHeight(), 2);

   hiddenWidth = fillString(hiddenWidth, 16);
   hiddenHeight = fillString(hiddenHeight, 16);
   posterisation = fillString(posterisation, 8);

   String header = hiddenWidth;
   header = header.concat(hiddenHeight);
   header = header.concat(posterisation);

   int newColor;
   int temp = 0;
   int temp2 = 0;
   int bitsToCheck = (int)logb(value, 2); //how many bits of each pixel we have to hide for given postarisation

   int zero = 0;
   int one = 1;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   String colorOfToHideBinary = "";

   outerLoop:
    for (int x = 0; x < hiding.getWidth(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < hiding.getHeight(); ++y) {
            int color = hiding.getImage().getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[1])[0];
            //filling header
            if(temp < header.length()){
                if(header.charAt(temp)== '0'){
                    newColor = color | zero;                        
                }else{ newColor = color | one;                        
                }temp++;
            //hiding image
            }else{
                /* 
                getting the value of the next pixel of the image to hide, only if temp ==0, 
                what means that it is the first pixel or each needed bits by the posterisation range
                has been already checked
                */
                if(temp2 == 0){

                    int colorOfToHide = toHide.getImage().getRaster().getPixel(i, j, new int[1]) [0];
                    colorOfToHideBinary = Integer.toString(colorOfToHide, 2);
                    colorOfToHideBinary = fillString(colorOfToHideBinary, 8);
                }                  
                //i check each value of the color in binary, but only as much as needed by the posterisation range                 
                if (colorOfToHideBinary.charAt(temp2) == '0'){
                    newColor = color | zero;
                }else { newColor = color | one;}
                temp2++;
                if (temp2 == bitsToCheck){
                    temp2 = 0;
                    j++;
                    if(j == toHide.getHeight()){
                        j = 0;
                        i++;                           
                    }
                }                
            }
            int[] newColorPixel = {newColor};
            hiding.getImage().getRaster().setPixel(x, y, newColorPixel);
             if(i == toHide.getWidth()){
                            break outerLoop;
            }
        }  
    }
    hiding.imageChanged();         
}

//decrypting image

public static ImageModel encodingOperation(ImageModel imgModel){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    String widthB = "";
    String heightB = "";
    String posterisationB = "";
    int temp = 0;
    int one = 1;

    /* loop for taking values from the header, seems to work pretty fine */
    outerLoop:
     for (int x = 0; x < imgModel.getWidth(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < imgModel.getHeight(); ++y) {
            int color = imgModel.getImage().getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[1])[0];

            if(temp<16){
                    if ((color & one) == one) widthB = widthB.concat("1");
                    else widthB = widthB.concat("0");
            }else if(temp < 32){
                    if ((color & one) == one) heightB = heightB.concat("1");
                    else heightB = heightB.concat("0");
            }else if(temp <40){
                    if ((color & one) == one) posterisationB = posterisationB.concat("1");
                    else posterisationB = posterisationB.concat("0");
            }else{
                    break outerLoop;
            }temp++; j++;               
        }i++;
    }  

    int width = Integer.parseInt(widthB, 2);
    int height = Integer.parseInt(heightB, 2);
    int posterisation = Integer.parseInt(posterisationB, 2);
    int bitsToCheck = (int)logb(posterisation+1, 2);

    int temp2 = 0;
    String colorInBinary = "";

    //preparing the canvas for the encoded image, width and height from the header
    ImageModel encryptedImage = ImageModel.fromHidden(width, height);

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    /*  encoding the image
        starting after the point after the header, saved in the variables i,j            
    */    
    outerLoop:
    for (int x = i; x < imgModel.getWidth(); ++x) {
        for (int y = j; y < imgModel.getHeight(); ++y) {
            int color = imgModel.getImage().getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[1])[0];           
            /* pixel by pixel reading color of the hidden image
                temp2 checks, where to stop - how many LSB of the hiding image keeps information bout one pixel of the hidden img
            */                
            if ((color & one) == one) colorInBinary = colorInBinary.concat("1");
                    else colorInBinary= colorInBinary.concat("0");
            temp2++;
            if (temp2 == bitsToCheck){
                temp2 = 0;
                //fullfilling the color to the right by the given posterisation range
                colorInBinary = complete(colorInBinary); 
                int newColor = Integer.parseInt(colorInBinary, 2);
                colorInBinary = "";
                int[] newColorPixel = {newColor};

                encryptedImage.getImage().getRaster().setPixel(a, b, newColorPixel);

                b++;
                if(b == height){
                    a++;
                    b=0;
                }if (a == width){
                    break outerLoop;
                }           
            }               
        }
    }
  return encryptedImage;  
}

public static double logb( double a, double b ){
    return Math.log(a) / Math.log(b);
}


public static void posterize(ImageModel imgModel, int value) {
    int[] lut = new int[256];
    float param1 = 255.0f / (value - 1);
    float param2 = 256.0f / (value);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        lut[i] = (int)((int)(i / param2) * param1);
    }
    useLUT(imgModel, lut);
}


public static void useLUT(ImageModel imgModel, int[] lut) {
    for (int x = 0; x < imgModel.getWidth(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < imgModel.getHeight(); ++y) {
            int color = imgModel.getImage().getRaster().getPixel(x, y, new int[1])[0];

            int[] newColorPixel = {lut[color]};
            imgModel.getImage().getRaster().setPixel(x, y, newColorPixel);
        }
    }        
    imgModel.imageChanged();
}
```

Comment: You can't expect us to just debug your code. You need to be more specific with "the encoding returns an image that differs from the image that was hidden". Differs how? What did you expect instead? Did you mean the decoding where you extract your hidden secret? Because the encoding is when you hide the secret. What have you tried so far? What results did you get? Do you have any suspicions of where the error might be, e.g, the code returns unexpected results after step x? Can you summarise how your algorithm works? Just saying you embed bits in the lsb is too broad.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about questions asking for debugging help.